# how to write first servlet class in Eclipsed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Helloworld
 */
@WebServlet("/Helloworld")

public class Helloworld extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Helloworld() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

I have created a class hello-world and added Servelte API but I am getting Error `@WebServlet("/Helloworld")` and show Error Messge **[The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type WebServlet]**.

Please tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html

Try to add atrribute value: @WebServlet(value="/Helloworld")